# "Add new item" button within asp.net mvc dropdown list

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Currently, I am adding items to a dropdown list in my asp.net mvc application by clicking on a link on the same page and adding an item to the database table that the dropdown list is bound to.

I want this "link" to be an item WITHIN the drop down list so the list items will look something like

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
- Add New Item

and when the user selects "add new item", a dialog will pop up where the user can enter something to add to the list.

I've been searching all over the internet for a solution to this and I cannot find anything, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to handle the `change` event of the `select` and if the value is "Add New Item", show your dialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should handle the event of your dropdownlist.. Then, call the dialog where the user can input some value in your dropdown. You can achieve something like this by using JQuery:

```
$('#dropdownId').change(function (){
    var drpValue = $('#dropdownId').val();
    if(drpValue == "Add New Item"){
        //call method or show your dialog here;
    }
});
```

There are still two ways you can manage to add it directly to your dropdown:

1. Post Back
2. Using Ajax

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to disable "Add New Item" as a selection when I submit the form as a whole? My form submits three values from three seperate dropdown lists

Comment: Hmmm.. A workaround will do. On your click event, remove the last index of your dropdown before posting it back. Will it be okay if you will upvote my answer? :)

Comment: Thanks! I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer :(

Comment: That's okay :) well, I do hope so that I helped you with your concern.